# Force qt to not call data() function on model

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreeview

I have a qtreeview based on model view and it works well.
Whenever I do a alt tab to go to other window and when I come back , qt again calls the data function because it needs to repaint itself ..
Is this required ? When I know that no data has changed and I want the view to remain as it is, is there a way to tell qt to not call the data function ? Another scenario is when you minimise and then maximize the window.. it again calls all those data functions for the view....Can this be optimised ?

Comment: The call to data() is optimized since the painting is optimized, in addition only certain items are called.

Comment: But I noticed that for this case where I minimise and maximize window, then the data function does get called for all the visible data that is to be shown. In case the model needs to get data from some other source (like from c++ to python) in my case, this is a penalty... Isn't it @eyllanesc

Comment: It is called because every time they interact with the window the whole window is repainted, and data() is called because for the view to be painted it is necessary to know the information of the model since based on it it is painted. Do you have a penalty? I don't believe, how do you measure that penalty? How slow does your program get? Do you have any objective evidence of what you point out?

Comment: If your `data()` method very hard so maybe it is better to implement some type of local cache inside your model, so when `data()` calls with non-changed values just return cache value.

Comment: @NishantSharma Not all the items are necessarily called, only the visible items, if you have few items then obviously all the items will be used but if you have 1000 rows but because of the size of your view you can only show 10 then only the data of those items will be called 10 rows

Comment: @NishantSharma The penalty from C++ to python is minimal, have you measured that penalty?

Comment: Well, I see a sluggishness... Though it could be a machine issue too... But I am just exploring if there is some way for more optimisation

Comment: @NishantSharma What if the error is caused by another part of your code?

Comment: @eyllanesc : Yeah... I do understand your point totally.... I was just exploring optimising some specific scenario....

Comment: @SerhiyKulish yes... I have already done that... I do see case where window is mimized and then maximised, then if machine is a little slow, you can see that row by row painting happening... I am just exploring if that could be optimised ..